# Convert datetime in python

Tags: python, datetime

How do i convert this datetime using python?

```
2017-10-16T08:27:16+0000
```

I tried to use strptime but getting ValueError: time data '2017-10-16T08:27:16+0000' does not match format 'The %d %B %Y at. %H:%M'

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-10-16T08:27:16+0000", "The %d %B %Y at. %H:%M")

'''
I want my output to look like this
The 16 october 2017 at. 08:27
'''
```

Comment: google strptime and strftime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First parse the string correctly, then print it in the desired format:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-10-16T08:27:16+0000", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(date.strftime("The %d %B %Y at. %H:%M"))
```

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.harvard.edu/rprasad/2011/09/21/python-string-to-a-datetime-object/
You have to first strip your date using `strptime()` and then rebuild it using `strftime()`

```
import datetime
time = "2017-10-16T08:27:16+0000"
stripedTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%Y-%m-%dT%I:%M:%S%z')

rebuildTime = stripedTime.strftime('The %d %B %Y at. %H:%M')
print(rebuildTime)
```